Get the type of an object such that I can put it into brackets of generic method
There is a generic method:
public T GetObject<T>() { ... }

I have an object someObject of some class type SomeClass which inherits from T, and I want to call GetType depending on the type of someObject.
The following does not work:
Type classType = someObject.GetType();
object ret = GetRay<classType>();

The compiler says:

classType is a variable but it is used like a type.

How do I need to put it?

How does your current method get someObject? If it's passed it as a parameter, can you make your own method generic as well?

You don't. That's not how generics work.  What exactly do you think you'd be achieving by doing that? If we know what you're actually trying to achieve, we may be able to explain how to achieve it.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever That may work for us, thanks!
